# How to make Python search through 2d list for a specific string?

Tags: python-3.10

I'm trying to set up a basic password system to practise my 2D lists and have a bit of a muck about but i can't seem to figure out how to get python to check one string against a 2d list

I've tried using if statements and list() but it wont work i am very new to python so any help would be much appreciated please excuse bad variable names

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI3Gz.png)

Comment: iterate through the list of list then iterate through each sublist

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ...

```
input_username != NAME_PASSWORDS
```

... you want syntax more like ...

```
input_username not in [ pair[0] for pair in NAME_PASSWORDS]
```

The list-comprehension creates a temporary list containing the first element from each pair in the list ie a temporary list of user-names
The `not in` keyword checks whether the list has an exact match item.

Syntax like ...

```
input_username not in [uname for uname, pwd in NAME_PASSWORDS]
```

... might make the purpose of the temporary list clearer. However, it requires the list strictly to have pairs.

Comment: Thank you so much I completely forgot about in